# Azure ARM template copy loop - object of objects

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to create below structure using ARM template copy loop:

```
{ 
 triggers:{
    "trigger1": {name:trigger1, subscription:xyz},
    "trigger2": {name:trigger2, subscription:abc},
    "trigger3": {name:trigger3, subscription:abc}
  }
}
```

using the copy loop and copy index

```
   "copy":[
            {
               "name":"triggers",
               "count":"[length(parameters('subscription_names'))]",
               "input":{ name: [concat ('trigger', copyIndex('triggers'))],
                         subscription: parameters('subscription_names')[copyIndex('triggers')]
                       }
             }
           ]
```

I get something like array of triggers :

```
    { 
     triggers:[
         {name:trigger1, subscription:xyz},
         {name:trigger2, subscription:abc},
         {name:trigger3, subscription:abc}
      ]
    }
```

Is there a way to convert or create object of objects with the azure ARM copy loop instead of array of objects?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
{ 
  triggers: {
    {name:trigger1, subscription:xyz},
    {name:trigger2, subscription:abc},
    {name:trigger3, subscription:abc}
  }
}
```

that is not a valid json, so you cant be using that snippet. the one you show on the bottom - is a valid one and can be used

Comment: Apologies the json structure is like above, I just changed

Comment: so the one you posted at the bottom now is also invalid, it can't be created by a copy function, but you should use the output provided by the copy function and just adjust the template to work with that

Comment: oh ok.. copy creates the structure at the bottom and as you said.. arm is complaining saying invalid structure... so let me check this output.. Thanks

Comment: the bottom you had originally is what it was creating, it cant be creating the one you posted now. and that one is a valid json and you can iterate over that and create something out of that